# I can't process numbers in a file in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

When I execute this code, it works fine but the output in "kredi.txt" doesn't appear correctly. For example, when I enter 1 for "hesapNo", stone for "soyisim", white for "isim", 20.50 for "bakiye", the output in "kredi.txt" looks like this:

```
[   stone          white          ÌÌÌÌÌÌ     €4@]
```

Why?  This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct musteriVerisi
{
    int hesapNo;
    char soyisim[15];
    char isim[15];
    double bakiye;
};

int main() {
    FILE *cfPtr;
    struct musteriVerisi musteri = { 0," "," ",0.0 };
    if ((cfPtr = fopen("kredi.txt", "r+")) == NULL)
        printf("DosyaAcilamadi\n");
    else {
        printf("HesapNo girin:"
                "(1 den 100 e kadar cikis icin 0 girin)");
        scanf("%d", &musteri.hesapNo);
        while (musteri.hesapNo != 0) {
            printf("soyisim,isim,bakiye giriniz:\n?");
            fscanf(stdin, "%s%s%lf", musteri.soyisim, musteri.isim, &musteri.bakiye);
            fseek(cfPtr, (musteri.hesapNo - 1) * sizeof(struct musteriVerisi), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&musteri, sizeof(struct musteriVerisi), 1, cfPtr);
            printf("HesapNo girin:\n?");
            scanf("%d", &musteri.hesapNo);
        }
        fclose(cfPtr);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The topic of the chapter containing this example in the book I study from is "Writing data to random-access file".

Answer (score 1):

```
    fwrite(&musteri, sizeof(struct musteriVerisi), 1, cfPtr);
```

That line of code makes no sense. You're just writing some binary garbage in memory to a file. There's no reason to expect that to make any sense when the program stops running -- who knows what internal format the system uses to store information.

For example:

```
char soyisim[15];
```

Say that contains a two character string with a terminating zero byte. What do the other 13 bytes contain? Do you know? I don't either. So *why are you writing unknown garbage to a file*?!

Comment: isn't that line for writing output in a file ? how should I change my code when I delete that line of code program doesnt do anything.

Comment: That's a line for writing output to a file, but you never prepared any output to go to the file. Instead, you just wrote a chunk of memory whose contents you don't know to the file. Before you write any output to a file, prepare a chunk of memory with precisely the contents you want to write to the file, and write that. *Where is the code for putting the data in the file in a sensible format that makes some kind of sense such that it's possible to read and understand it?* If you have no code to do that, then you're expecting it to happen by magic.